# qml logging category output not shown in console

Tags: qt, qml

What is needed to make the qml logging category work, e.g. show output in the console?
Currently only `"default message"` is shown. I expected also `"category message"` to appear in the console. A different log level, for example `LoggingCategory.Info`, also did not help.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-loggingcategory.html

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        LoggingCategory {
            id: category
            name: "com.qt.category"
            defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Warning
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("default message")
            console.log(category, "category message");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
After the answer I played around to see combinations that work... not really intuitive in my opinion, unlike most of Qt's great documentation

Summarizing working combinations:

- LoggingCategory.Debug -> console.(log/info/warn/error/debug)
- LoggingCategory.Info-> console.(info/warn/error)
- LoggingCategory.Warning-> console.(warn/error)
- LoggingCategory.Critical -> console.(error)

Playground:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        LoggingCategory {
            id: qml_custom_debug
            name: "qml.custom.debug"
            defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Debug
        }
        LoggingCategory {
            id: qml_custom_info
            name: "qml.custom.info"
            defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Info
        }
        LoggingCategory {
            id: qml_custom_warn
            name: "qml.custom.warn"
            defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Warning
        }
        LoggingCategory {
            id: qml_custom_critical
            name: "qml.custom.critical"
            defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Critical
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {

            console.log("Component.onCompleted")
            console.log(qml_custom_debug,       "category debug - log: Component.onCompleted")
            console.info(qml_custom_debug,      "category debug - info: Component.onCompleted")
            console.warn(qml_custom_debug,      "category debug - warn: Component.onCompleted")
            console.error(qml_custom_debug,     "category debug - error: Component.onCompleted")
            console.debug(qml_custom_debug,     "category debug - debug: Component.onCompleted")

            console.log(qml_custom_info,        "category info  - log: Component.onCompleted")
            console.info(qml_custom_info,       "category info  - info: Component.onCompleted")
            console.warn(qml_custom_info,       "category info  - warn: Component.onCompleted")
            console.error(qml_custom_info,      "category info  - error: Component.onCompleted")
            console.debug(qml_custom_info,      "category info  - debug: Component.onCompleted")

            console.log(qml_custom_warn,        "category warn  - log: Component.onCompleted")
            console.info(qml_custom_warn,       "category warn  - info: Component.onCompleted")
            console.warn(qml_custom_warn,       "category warn  - warn: Component.onCompleted")
            console.error(qml_custom_warn,      "category warn  - error: Component.onCompleted")
            console.debug(qml_custom_warn,      "category warn  - debug: Component.onCompleted")

            console.log(qml_custom_critical,    "category critical  - log: Component.onCompleted")
            console.info(qml_custom_critical,   "category critical  - info: Component.onCompleted")
            console.warn(qml_custom_critical,   "category critical  - warn: Component.onCompleted")
            console.error(qml_custom_critical,  "category critical  - error: Component.onCompleted")
            console.debug(qml_custom_critical,  "category critical  - debug: Component.onCompleted")
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
qml: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.debug: category debug - log: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.debug: category debug - info: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.debug: category debug - warn: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.debug: category debug - error: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.debug: category debug - debug: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.info: category info  - info: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.info: category info  - warn: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.info: category info  - error: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.warn: category warn  - warn: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.warn: category warn  - error: Component.onCompleted
qml.custom.critical: category critical  - error: Component.onCompleted
```

**Update 2:**

Also learned that them qml logging also is influenced by settings made in c++, for example

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(
      QStringLiteral("*.info=false\n"
                     "*.debug=false\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultLogLevel` is the filter for your messages. If you call `console.log()` with `defaultLogLevel` of Warning, the message is filtered out. A call to `console.warn()` will be shown.

You can play a bit with log levels and default log levels than you see what is happening:

```
Item {
    LoggingCategory {
        id: category
        name: "com.qt.category"
        // defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Debug
        // defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Warning
        defaultLogLevel: LoggingCategory.Critical
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("debug message");
        console.warn(category, "warn message");
        console.error(category, "error message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the documentation wrong in this case? It gives a bad example.

Comment: The example is indeed a bit misleading. The naming LoggingCategory for something used to filter message might be unlucky.